# Export csv Not working for the custom attributes customer grid Magento2

Tags: magento2, custom-attributes, export, customer-attribute, magento2.3.0

Below showing code is my customer_listing.xml, export csv not working when selected checkbox's export from grid.

```
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="customer_columns" class="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns">         
        <column name="customer_clv" class="Vendorname\Modulename\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Customerclv">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                    <item name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Customer Lifetime Value</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">81</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="predicted_average_profit" class="Vendorname\Modulename\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Customerclv">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                    <item name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Predicted Average Transaction Value</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">82</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="predicted_no_of_purchases" class="Vendorname\Modulename\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Customerclv">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                    <item name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Predicted No Of Purchases for next 10 weeks</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">83</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="probability_no_of_purchases" class="Vendorname\Modulename\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Customerclv">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                    <item name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Probability</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">84</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <actionsColumn name="actions" class="Vendorname\Modulename\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\ClvActions">
            <settings>
                <indexField>entity_id</indexField>
            </settings>
        </actionsColumn>       
    </columns> </listing>
```

Comment: I am stuck with the same problem. Did you find a solution yet?